# What is the proper capitalization of "Question" and "Answer"?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, terminology, capitalization

Basically, I've been capitalizing Question and Answer when referring to Stack Exchange Questions and Answers - that is, the pieces of content on the site - to distinguish them from just questions and answers in a more generic sense. For instance, "Please don't answer in the comments. Write your answers in the Answers." After someone asked me why I was doing that, though, I realized that there might be an official way of referring to them, and I figured that I could ask about it on here.

So, does Stack Exchange officially have any capitalization or style guidelines for referring to Questions and Answers on their site?

Answer (score 5):

Stack Exchange content is expected to follow the general rules of English* grammar. English uses capitals for nouns when they're proper nouns (and at the beginning of a sentence), and 'question' and 'answer' are, generally speaking, not proper nouns, so they should not be capitalized. However, you might have stumbled upon an exception here: on a Q&A page, there is an 'Answers section'. One could argue that 'Answers' there *is* a proper noun, since it identifies something unique. The header of that section even says "12 Answers" (even though I would write that with a lowercase 'A').

> Please don't answer in the Comments section. Write your answers in the Answers section.

would 'sound' very natural to me. (But please note that I'm not a native English speaker.)

*<sub>: language sites, and non-English Stack Overflow sites are the obvious exceptions.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

My preference would be to capitalize the first letters of Questions, Answers and Comments when referring to the sections we have reserved for questions, answers and comments to be written.  By doing that it makes it easy to refer to "questions people have asked in Comments".

However, early in my days using Stack Exchange sites a much higher reputation user suggested not using a capital letter, and so I switched to not capitalizing them.  Consequently, I have to refer to "questions people have asked in area reserved for comments".

To this day it feels not quite right to leave them uncapitalized.

I am a native (Australian) English speaker with more British than American influence in how I write and speak.